# combination of \underset{} and \ul{} prevents linebreak

Tags: line-breaking

Here is the MWE. I am sorry for not putting it earlier.

[image]

```
\documentclass [11pt,letterpaper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}

This is the example to show that whether the use of ``underset" is correct. If underlined text is $\underset{1}{\text{\ul{one or two words}}}$ it is fine; however if it is $\underset{2}{\text{\ul{very very long text, such as this, the underlined text does not break line, see this. The line from here is not published.}}}$ \\

$\underset{3}{\text{\ul{Second request is that if the underlined text shows up in two lines,}}}$ 

$\underset{3}{\text{\ul{the numeral below that, in this case `3' should also show up in each line.}}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a working example,not just fragments of code in the running text ;-

Comment: `\underset` is not really appropriate for long sentence. Perhaps you may write it in the main text?

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I have a long passage and at multiple places, a word/phrase/very long sentence is underlined and beneath that a numeral as a question marker is placed. \underset works well for me till the string length is short. I do not know which is the best way to get this. Could you pl help. Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Pl. see the MWE with output. I am sorry for not putting it up earlier.

Comment: `\ul` alow line breaks with the `soulpos` package in normal text, but the problem is that  you will need a `\parbox` to break lines in a  `\text` in math mode even without `\ul`,  and anyway then  `\underset` will put only  one number  under one object (the long line or the paragraph).

Comment: Well, the problem is that what you want is impossible; where should LaTeX place the little `2`, in your opinion?

Comment: Well, the placement of numerals below the underlined text is a secondary issue and what I think that LaTex puts it exactly below the midpoint of the underline, so that is fine with me. My primary issue is of line-break.